# How to adjust height of nested div according to its content in accordion slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found a jsfiddle that is similar to mine.

http://jsfiddle.net/bigvax/hEApL/

```
--HTML
<div class="accordion-expand-holder">
    <button type="button" class="open">Expand all</button>
    <button type="button" class="close">Collapse all</button>
</div>

<div id="accordion">
     <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <div>
        <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.</p>
    </div>

    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <div>
        <p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna.</p>
    </div>

    <h3>Section 3</h3>
    <div>
        <p>Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis. Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.</p>
        <ul>
            <li>List item one</li>
            <li>List item two</li>
            <li>List item three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <h3>Section 4</h3>
    <div>
        <p>Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia mauris vel est.</p>
        <p>Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
    </div>
</div>


--Javascript / JQuery
// Accordion - Expand All #01
$(function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        collapsible:true,
        active:false
    });
    var icons = $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "icons" );
    $('.open').click(function () {
        $('.ui-accordion-header').removeClass('ui-corner-all').addClass('ui-accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-corner-top').attr({
            'aria-selected': 'true',
            'tabindex': '0'
        });
        $('.ui-accordion-header-icon').removeClass(icons.header).addClass(icons.headerSelected);
        $('.ui-accordion-content').addClass('ui-accordion-content-active').attr({
            'aria-expanded': 'true',
            'aria-hidden': 'false'
        }).show();
        $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
        $('.close').removeAttr("disabled");
    });
    $('.close').click(function () {
        $('.ui-accordion-header').removeClass('ui-accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-corner-top').addClass('ui-corner-all').attr({
            'aria-selected': 'false',
            'tabindex': '-1'
        });
        $('.ui-accordion-header-icon').removeClass(icons.headerSelected).addClass(icons.header);
        $('.ui-accordion-content').removeClass('ui-accordion-content-active').attr({
            'aria-expanded': 'false',
            'aria-hidden': 'true'
        }).hide();
        $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
        $('.open').removeAttr("disabled");
    });
    $('.ui-accordion-header').click(function () {
        $('.open').removeAttr("disabled");
        $('.close').removeAttr("disabled");

    });
});

--CSS
body {
    font-family:Arial, Tahoma, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:65%;
}
.accordion-expand-holder {
    margin:10px 0;
}
.accordion-expand-holder .open, .accordion-expand-holder .close {
    margin:0 10px 0 0;
}
```

In the output, section3 div has more content and its height is greater than other sections. So it looks like the height of the other divs (section1, section2 and section4) is also set to height of section3. Is there a way to adjust the height of all the divs according to its content ? section1 and section2 have more blank space at the bottom, since the height is larger than the content. Appreciate your help on this. Thanks !

Comment: you can set each pane's height manually, or just adjust the one that is a problem. sometimes the overall accord needs a certain height though, which complicates things.

Comment: Ok. Is there a way to set limit the height of div to it's content ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the heightStyle option set to "content" when initializing the accordion I think it will have the style you want

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
    collapsible:true,
    active:false,
    heightStyle:"content"
});
```

https://jqueryui.com/accordion/#no-auto-height

Comment: Thank you @Walrus. That helped. I had this jquery, but was missing the jquery references